# Android - How to edit RelativeLayout shape

Tags: android, layout, shapes

I'm using a pop up window as `Activity class` with a layout, when the `button` is pressed, a pop up window will appear. what I want is to edit the `shape` of my pop up window that is a `RelativeLayout`. thanks

this is my pop_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_shape"
    tools:context="com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal.FinalResults.Final_Result_Grade_4">

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my layout_shape

```
    <solid
        android:color="#00B0BE" >
    </solid>

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#C4CDE0" >
    </stroke>

    <padding
        android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp"    >
    </padding>

    <corners
        android:radius="40dp"   >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

A screenshot from my XML, i want to remove that whitespace on the side, i know its from the layout background, can i use transparency? because this will pop up on other layout activity so i need only is the blue shape. btw the layout code is from @Sabari thanks

[image]

Comment: Show your code, what you have tried so far, maybe add Screenshots/some Image of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Amy edited see my post

Comment: this seems to be the window background. make sure what theme the activity uses and be sure to remove the window background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

Add a custom drawable

custom_shape.xml

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"   >

    <solid
        android:color="#00B0BE" >
    </solid>

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#C4CDE0" >
    </stroke>

    <padding
        android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp"    >
    </padding>

    <corners
        android:radius="40dp"   >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

And add background for the RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_shape">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Testing" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it still has white space on the sides, coming from the layout. see my edited post

Comment: yes it is due to setting radius=40dp in custom_shape.xml. If you dont need, remove that "  <corners  android:radius="40dp" > </corners>"

Comment: no im talking about the white color, if i take out the `corner radius` there will be no shape and it's like I only put a blue background on my layout

Comment: Yes that is parent control background color. Now i have modified the above code. In that code set parent relativelayouts background color to semi transparent color.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your,

**layout_shape** as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#2eb8b8"></solid>
    <corners android:radius="30dp"></corners>
</shape>
```

**pop_up.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_shape"
        tools:context="com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal.FinalResults.Final_Result_Grade_4">

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: tell me if facing any issue @Lynerd

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reduce the radius of the corners in the custom shape

`<corners android:radius:"10dp"></corners>`